# Unable to begin a distributed transaction for linked server from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have created a linked server from SQL Server 2005 to Oracle 11g. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sErVb.png)

I can select or insert into the table of the linked server by Transact-SQL in Query Analyzer but when I create a trigger in SQL for Insert to Oracle, it shows this error:

"OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "BCSS" returned message "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ".

The operation could not be performed because of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "BCSS" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18D0Y.png)

I don't know why. Please, help me solve this problem. Thanks!

My trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [import_test]
   ON  [dbo].[Test123] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @eventid  INT
    SET @eventid  = (SELECT ID  FROM inserted) 
    INSERT INTO BCSS..SYSPTTB.EVENTS(EventID) VALUES (@eventid)
END
```

I have configured MSDTC on both server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgna3.png)

Comment: Have you configured the distributed transaction coordinator yet?

Comment: hi @DenisRubashkin
yes, i have configured MSDTC on both server

Comment: i have tried link from sql server to another sql server (2005) and same error :((( i can not understand because i can insert by Transact-SQL in Query Analyzer but can not run it in TRIGGER :(((((((

Comment: plz help me!!!! I have tried many solutions in 2 days but it still error :(((((